# Email script not working (PHP)

Tags: php

So I wrote a email script, but for some reason, it is now not working, I don't even remember changing it... I think I changed an echo output but when I reverted it back to the old version  it still doesn't work so I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I put it through a php checker and it came back as the code is fine!

Here is my code, please help!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['username']) ||
    !isset($_POST['emailto']) ||
    !isset($_POST['emailsubject']) ||
    !isset($_POST['emailmessage'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$username = $_POST['username']; // required
$emailto = $_POST['emailto']; // required
$emailsubject = $_POST['emailsubject']; // required
$emailmessage = $_POST['emailmessage']; //  required


function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message = clean_string($emailmessage);
$email_message .= "\n\nNOTE: Sent from a ComputerCraft User (Using L2P Live Email Client).\n";


// create email headers
$headers = "From: " . $username ."@dannysmc.com \r\n".
'Reply-To: ' . $username . '@dannysmc.com '."\r\n" .
"Return-Path: email_catcher@dannysmc.com\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers)){
    echo 'TRUE';
}else{
    echo '<pre>';
print_r(error_get_last()); //it will show you the error. Remove it on production 
}
?>

//mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: post the error here?

Comment: please define "not working"!

Comment: Where do you use it? On shared hosting or localhost?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't send the email? No error comes back from it... That's why I am confused!

Comment: check the spam-folder of the mail-account

Comment: I have it doesn't show...

Comment: "not working" "doesn't work" what?

Answer (score 0):

Checked the code.

Its sending emails.

Only issue I found is, you closed a php tag in wrong place.

```
?>

//mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

remove the closing tag before the commented mail function.